Painless script for finding Nth instance in log message
In Kibana we have a field called log message, we have entire message, to trim that trying to write a script for the same
Please find below the pipeline to extract first 30 words from the message:
PUT ingest/pipeline extract_30words

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
